# Can you initiate a connection from a bound port?

Tags: networking, tcp, low-level

If I have a service running on some port, let's say port 80, would I be able to initiate a connection with a different service using that port as the source port? Given that I have full level access to the computer, i.e. root, low-level drivers, etc. Is it possible to do so or do tcp specifications prevent something like that from happening?

Comment: No. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I don't want to do it, I need to know if it's possible.

Comment: Why do you need to know if it's possible?

Comment: For research purposes.

Comment: That's not actually an answer, as a researcher should know. It's just a circularity.

Comment: The idea is: if an attacker gains control of a server, he could initiate outbound communication from a port that the server already communicates on, thus lowering his chances of being detected. I needed to know if it's possible: it is. If you have something useful to contribute, please do.

Comment: A connection from an outbound port 80 would be viewed with some suspicion, I would have thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, I have an ssh server running on my computer and I tried doing an nmap scan from port 22, worked without a problem and the scan was successful.

sudo nmap -sS xxx.xx.xx.0/24 -g 22 -p 80

I have also discussed it with some experts and there is nothing in TCP specifications which would prevent that from happening. The only problem can occur at implementation level.